# Find the equation of common tangent of the circle $x^2+y^2-8x=0$ and hyperbola $\frac{x^2}{9}-\frac{y^2}{4}=1$

Tags: conic-sections

Equation the condition of tangency of both the conics 
$$4m\pm \sqrt {9m^2-4}=4\sqrt {1+m^2}$$my problem is easy. Are there any tips to reduce such heavy calculations?

Comment: Have you been introduced to the $3 \times 3$ matrix associated with a conic curve ?

Comment: That's an equation for $m$, which I assume that's the slope of the tangent. Do you have the intercept as well?

Comment: $9X^2-4Y^2-1=0$ and $Y^2-\frac{X}{2}-\frac1{16}=0$ are the dual conics, and they intersect in $(\frac12,\pm\frac{\sqrt{5}}{4})$, so the two common tangents are $\frac12 x\pm\frac{\sqrt{5}}{4} y+1=0.$

Comment: @JeanMarie not yet

Comment: @Andrei no, that’s all I have. $m$ is indeed the slope of the tangents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of any tangent of the hyperbola at $(3\sec t,2\tan t)$ will be $$x(3\sec  t)/9-y(2\tan t)/4=1\iff 2x\tan t -3y\tan t-6=0$$

Now if this has to be a tangent of the given circle, the distance from the center will be same

$$4=\dfrac{|2\sec t(4)+0-6|}{\sqrt{(2\sec t)^2+(3\tan t)^2}}$$

Take square in both sides and use $$\tan ^2t=\sec^2t-1$$ to form a quadratic equation in $\sec t$